# Windows Mobile: Inner join query doesnt work

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, sql-server-ce

I'm Already develop from earlier windows mobile apps. 
i have table:

```
assetNo nvarchar(20)
roomno nvarchan(8)
status ncarchar(4)

Asset no     RoomNo        Status
001          DPN            0           
002          TRG            4           
003          SHW            1           
004          ROOM           1           
005          DPN            1   
.
.
```

i want to collect by status and separate status 0 and all record, group by `roomno`

the output will be like this:

```
RoomNo   Status0   sllstatus
DPN      1         2
TRG      0         1
SHW      0         1
ROM      1         1
```

i have query like this:

```
SELECT a.RoomNo , a.Scanmanual AS ScanManual, b.allscan AS AllScan
FROM
  (SELECT roomno, count(*) AS scanmanual
   FROM assets
   WHERE status = 0
   GROUP BY roomno) AS a 
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT roomno, count(*) AS allscan
   FROM assets
   GROUP BY roomno) AS b ON (a.roomno=b.roomno)
```

this query running well in sql server compact edition, but when i run in Visual Studio 2005 having error "**there was an error parsing the query, [ Token line number = 1, Toker ofset = 78,  in error = select ]"**

```
private void Summary_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
        string sql ="SELECT a.RoomNo , a.Scanmanual AS ScanManual, b.allscan AS        AllScan from (select roomno, count(*) AS scanmanual   from assets WHERE status = 0 group by roomno) AS a inner join (select roomno,  count(*) AS allscan  FROM assets group by roomno) as b on(a.roomno=b.roomno)"


        SqlCeDataAdapter da = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(sql, dbConn);
            da.Fill(ds, "Assets");

            dataGrid.DataSource = ds.Tables["Assets"];
        }
        catch (SqlCeException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
                "DB Operation SDF", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation,
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        finally
        {
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            da.SelectCommand.Dispose();
            da.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

what should i do to fix this error?? thanks

Comment: Is `status` in your SQL Query an SQL Keyword or a SQL Table field? Perhaps Visual Studio does not know either.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely dues to an unsupported query.  Check it by breaking it down into the sub-parts and running them individually - this can be done right in Studio against the database on the desktop using Server Explorer.  I don't know if count(*) is supported (IIRC it wasn't in earlier versions, though it may well be in 3.5).  I'm not sure if aliasing is supported.  I'm fairly sure using the results of a query as an input isn't.

Error aside, this is a complex query - too complex.  Joining the results of two other joins (which are also grouped) throws an immediate red flag for performance and memory usage on an embedded system in my eye.

If I saw this in a code review of a customer's code, I'd strongly suggest that the tables be denormalized to reduce all of this work (you're not on a quad-core server machine with gigabytes of RAM). Maybe trying to store the data in a way that closer resembles what you want as output would be a good step as well.  I'd also recommend trying to break it down to smaller units of work that could be done with less query processor interaction (I'm a fan of not using the query parser at all).

If I saw this while reviewing code by someone that worked for me, I'd slap them as it's a direct violation of "keep it simple" which is what you must do in a resource-limited environment.

Comment: The statement COUNT(*) is supported in SQLCE 3.5
As recommended break the statements down. You can Group and Join in runtime via LINQ.

Comment: ctacke:

thanks btw ctacke, the purpose of this project for display the output like that. ever u do the other way for simplyfy. mybe using the other solution to kick this goal?